# Word for "mid-sized wild mammalian land animal," equivalent to Sanskrit "mṛga."

Tags: nouns, translation, animals

I am looking for an English translation for the Sanskrit word *mṛga*.  This word refers to wild animals that are somewhat below the top of the food chain.  The archetypical *mṛga* is a deer.  They are animals that may themselves be herbivorous, carnivorous or omnivorous, but they are usually also the prey of other animals.  Lions or tigers, for example, would not be referred to by *mṛga*.  At the same time, insects, birds and fish are also not *mṛga*s.  It seems they are mammalian land animals that are relatively low on the food chain: deer, rabbits, beavers, voles, mongooses, etc.

Edited to clarify that *mṛga*s can also be herbivores.

Also, to add the context of the translation: an analogy is being drawn between a mirage and certain Buddhist scriptures whose statements should not be taken at face value.  The *mṛga*s think that there is water in the mirage, and so hanker after it, even though there is no water there.  In the same way, foolish people think there is absolute truth to certain statements in the scriptures, and so hanker after them, but in fact there is ultimately no truth to those statements.

Comment: Note that deer, rabbits and beaver are vegetarian, not carnivore/omnivore. That is what places them low in the food chain. The first two might be called **grazers**.

Comment: Ungulate - this would refer to cattle, deer and camels, even horses - basically anything with hooves. Rabits, voles and mongooses - not so much. Aren't the vole and mongoose carnivores too? If you're looking at things that can be eaten by people then perhaps "game", but then that could include certain birds.

Comment: Now I'm thinking "prey animal" or  "quarry" if it's being hunted. Then "critter" or "varmint",  generic terms for animal. "Creature" may be too broad. Could you narrow your requirements by giving us the context of usage?

Comment: I think "game" captures the sense in a vague way, but is not exact.  They are usually "prey animals" so that also is somewhat accurate.  The problem is that the word in Sanskrit doesn't explicitly carry the sense of being hunted, so this would generally awkwardly stick out in a translation.

Comment: Lesser mammals? I don’t think English has a single word for this.

Comment: The origin of the word [deer](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=deer) is in an Old English word that covered many species, but it has been restricted in modern English to mean only members of family Cervidae. AFAIK we haven't replaced OE *deor* with any comparable word in modern English.

Comment: That page on the origin of the English word "deer" is fascinating (it also mentions the Sanskrit "mṛga"!)  Maybe I will just go with "deer" since that connection is so felicitous, and "mṛga" can, in a more restricted sense, refer to deer.

Comment: @Bitterdreggs. Just for the record - no, voles aren't carnivores.

Comment: @Bitterdreggs. I've upvoted you but, In natural history, they are known as "prey species".

Comment: @KateBunting Ahh, no, fair enough.

Comment: @ThePhoton  Also I never realized that the German "tier" is a cognate with the English 'deer."

Comment: @Paul, there's also a term, "beasts of the fields" that is used in Bible translations and religious discussions. But it's freighted with huge baggage, including some people interpreting it to include people with certain colors of skin.